# Why is Heroku unable to cd to my frontend React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I keep getting this error message when I git push my backend to heroku:

```
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:
remote:        > mp-backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_eaac46c4d4704cb2a35221c2068a754a
remote:        > cd map-project && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build
remote:
remote: sh: 1: cd: can't cd to map-project
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 2
remote: npm ERR! mp-backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `cd map-project && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 2
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the mp-backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
```

Leading to a ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined).

I do not understand. I added this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd map-project && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  }
```

to the package.json for my backend and then ran

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

while cd'd to my backend. What keeps causing my build to fail?

additional code that may help:

```
//my backend under folder mp-backend
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const populartimes = require('populartimes.js');

//Node Geocoder
const NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
const options = {
  provider: 'google',
  apiKey: 
};
const geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);

const getWeekDay = () => {
  typical getDay codes
}

const unRendered = 'https://i.imgur.com/fgSeO4a.png';
const Rendered = 'https://i.imgur.com/sg9a1sG.png';

//Markers
const markers = [an array of marker objects]

const findLatLong = async function findLatLong(){
    for(let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        const temp = await geocoder.geocode(markers[i].address)
        markers[i].position.lat = temp[0].latitude;
        markers[i].position.lng = temp[0].longitude;
    }
}

const fillNewMarker = async function fillNewMarker(num){
  const i = num;
  let temp;
  let data;
  await populartimes(markers[i].placeID)
  .then(out => {data = out; temp = 'Currently ' + data.now.currently + ' full.'})
  .catch(() => {temp = 'There is currently no data available.'});
  markers[i].busy = temp;
}

// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'map-project/build')));

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies


app.get('/api/getMarkers', async (req,res) => {
    await findLatLong();
    console.log('Find LatLng Complete')
    //await fillPopularity();
    //console.log('Find Business Complete')
    var mark = markers;
    res.json(mark);
    console.log('Sent Markers');
    console.log(markers);
});

app.post('/api/newMarker', async (req,res) => {
    console.log('Request Recieved');
    const n = req.body.index;
    console.log(n);
    await fillNewMarker(n);
    console.log('Retrieve Data For New Marker Complete');
    markers[n].icon = Rendered;
    var mark = markers;
    res.json(mark);
    console.log('Sent Markers');
    console.log(markers);
})

app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/map-project/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your folder structure? What does your project look like?

You haven't provided enough information for anyone to help you.

Edit:

You have two options here, mono-repo and poly-repo. Basically, do you want your front and back ends always tied together (mono-repo) or do you want them to be entirely separate things (poly-repo)? While I am a huge fan of mono-repos, even with large scopes, don't let me necessarily persuade you either way without doing your own research. I think a mono-repo would be better for you in this situation, as they are less work to manage.

Here's an example of a folder structure for your project:

```
my-project
----.git
----packages
--------back-end
--------front-end
----README.md
----(any other whole-project type files)
```

Your whole project will be under one Git repository. See your issue was that Git only tracks the folder you're in and down. So if you put Git in `packages/backend`, it'll only find and track that folder's children. Meaning when you push, anything not in `packages/backend` just doesn't exist.

This solution I propose has you tie the two packages quite closely. When you push to git or heroku, both your front and back end will be together. This also lets you handle some other tooling better, like say documentation. You can add instructions for deploying the system as a whole, rather than an individual part.

Comment: I have both my Frontend(Map-Project) and backend(mp-backend) inside my C:/users/me folder. I have also updated my post to include the code I believe to be related? I am very new to implementing frontend/backend and deploying so please forgive me for my ignorance. I have also only called git init on my backend and done nothing related to git with my frontend.

Comment: If you've only ran `git init` on your backend then the front end literally won't exist when you push it to an external source. Give me a minute and I'm going to update my post with options for how you should handle this.

Comment: should i remove the git from my backend part then and restart following your example?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to go mono-repo, then yes. If you want to manage the front and back end as individual pieces, then no. You're probably going to need to update your run command too.

Comment: I decided to go mono-repo. I deleted the git from the backend file and then proceeded to organize my files as you suggested. I then ran git init, git add . , git commit -m "Initial", heroku create, and then git push heroku master on the my-project folder. I received an error that a buildpack was undeteced so I set the heroku buildpack to nodejs, and ran git push again. However I receive another error saying that the buildpack is not detected(I'm guessing they don't detect the nodejs from the backend?).

Comment: When you push, remember that Heroku will be in that root directory, in `my-project`. You need to give it instructions relative to where it is at.